# Getting address from coordinates fail with error

Tags: flutter, location, geocoding

I am using placemarkFromCoordinates to get the current address by giving current location.

I am using

```
geocoding: ^2.0.4
```

with following code ;

```
List<Placemark> p = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
          pos.latitude, pos.longitude,
          localeIdentifier: "en");
```

The problem I have is it gives following error when i called it.

```
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1960)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.getFromLocation(ILocationManager.java:949)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:133)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at com.baseflow.geocoding.Geocoding.placemarkFromCoordinates(Geocoding.java:54)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at com.baseflow.geocoding.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onPlacemarkFromCoordinates(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:120)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at com.baseflow.geocoding.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:40)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:296)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:320)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404): Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1960)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at android.location.IGeocodeProvider$Stub$Proxy.getFromLocation(IGeocodeProvider.java:144)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding(10404):  at com.android.server.location.GeocoderProxy$1.run(GeocoderProxy.java:79)
```

I am running the application on the simulator though...

Can anyone provide some advice what is causing this issue?

Comment: can anyone provide a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

recently my app was working fine, but suddenly it threw exactly the same error. I'm not sure but I think the error is because of the limited access to the `API` provided by the free access of the `geocoding` service. However I close the emulator and open the `Device Manager` and `wipe` the emulator data, then reopen the emulator and run the app and the error is gone!